# Matplotlib imshow in Pycharm Ipython not always displaying image

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm IDE for Ipython and like it a lot. However, recently I'm having trouble with the matplotlib pyplot imshow function. Sometimes it works properly and displays an image but other times it just hangs (the cell is not executed, its labeled by the asterisk). You can execute additional cells after this with the image never being displayed. Im on OS X mavericks, using pycharm 5, latest ipython and matplotlib versions, enthought canopy python 2.7.. anyone experiencing something similar and worked out a solution?

Answer (score 23):

The code might be helpful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Adding the plt.show() line fixed it for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

and also use the "Scientific Mode " under the "View" menu. It will be shown in that panel.

Comment: Adding the plt.show() line fixed it for me.  Thanks.